# How to get performancepoint scorecard values via pmservice webservice?

Tags: performancepoint

I need to get the values from a scorecard in PerformancePoint/SharePoint 2010.

I have setup the code below. This fetches the objects just fine from PerformancePoint

```
BIMonitoringAuthoringServiceSoapClient client = new BIMonitoringAuthoringServiceSoapClient("BIMonitoringAuthoringServiceSoap");

client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Identification;

string listUrl = "/ops/Dashboards/Lists/PerformancePoint Content/";
FirstClassElement[] fcos = client.GetListItems(listUrl);

Kpi kpi = client.GetKpi(new RepositoryLocation() { ItemUrl = "/ops/Dashboards/Lists/PerformancePoint Content/27_.000" });
string kpimdx = client.GetMdx(new RepositoryLocation() { ItemUrl = "/ops/Dashboards/Lists/PerformancePoint Content/27_.000" });

Scorecard scorecard = client.GetScorecard(new RepositoryLocation() { ItemUrl = "/ops/Dashboards/Lists/PerformancePoint Content/38_.000" });
string scorecardmdx = client.GetMdx(new RepositoryLocation() { ItemUrl = "/ops/Dashboards/Lists/PerformancePoint Content/38_.000" });
```

The question is what how can you get the actual/target/state/etc from the scorecard?

---

Note: I started looking for MDX that might be behind the control, so I could query analysis services myself.

The KPIs/Scorecard don't seem to have MDX directly accessible via the client.GetMdx function.

Also I didn't mention that BIMonitoringAuthoringServiceSoapClient comes when I setup a WCF service to PMService.